# Compass (SASS) rule with pseudo class

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is it possible to generate css rule for element for normal state and some other pseudo state like this:

```
.heading-link, .heading-link:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

with

```
.heading-link {
    color: $state-info-text;
    &:hover {
        color: $state-info-text;
    }
}
```

I got

```
.heading-link {
  color: #538DA7;
}
.heading-link:hover {
  color: #538DA7;
}
```

What is not as expected, plus I have to write rule for color twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parent selector (`&`) by itself, in addition to other selectors inside nested blocks.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/b035a51e696ebd9e2162)</kbd>

```
$state-info-text: #538DA7;

.heading-link {
    &, &:hover {
        color: $state-info-text;
    }
}
```

Compiles to

```
.heading-link, .heading-link:hover {
  color: #538DA7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Sass's built in `@extend` function for this.

```
$state-info-text: red;

.heading-link {
    color: $state-info-text;
    &:hover {
        @extend .heading-link;
    }
}
```

Gives the output:

```
.heading-link, .heading-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: `@extend` will combine selectors. `.heading-link:hover` will get *all* the properties of `.heading-link`. This may not be desirable. [Example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/3553a438c41ea817c1e9).

Comment: May not, also may be :)